# Почему int автоматически не преобразовывается в больший long в java?

Tags: преобразование, java, синтаксис

Встретился с куском кода, в котором происходит ошибка выполнения:

```
class Runner { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Object[] array = new Long[1]; 
        array[0] = 1; 
        System.out.println(array[0]); 
    } 
}
```

Как написано в объяснения на http://muliver.org, где нашел такой тест: "В данном случае произойдёт ошибка выполнения из-за попытки присвоить объект неверного типа в массив объектов.", но почему не преобразовывается в long?

Answer (score 1):

Это проблема имплементации генериков в Java. Массивы не должны быть [ковариантны](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Covariant_arrays_in_Java_and_C.23) по типу элемента: `Long[]` не есть `Object[]` даже если `Long` есть `Object`.

Проблема в строчке

```
Object[] array = new Long[1];
```

Она, по-хорошему, не должна бы компилироваться.

Если вместо этого написать

```
Long[] array = new Long[1];
```

то компилятор совершенно правильно не разрешит присвоение несовместимого типа.

У C#, кстати, та же проблема.

Comment: "Long[] не есть Object[]" - не вижу связи с сутью вопроса, ковариантность массивов здесь ни причём, так как выражение array[0] = 1l; компилируется и выполняется без ошибок.

Comment: @guci: Проблема в том, что и выражение `array[0] = 1`, и даже `array[0] = "abcdef"` компилируется без ошибок. Но выполняется с ошибками.

Если бы дизайн массивов был правилен, это бы отловилось на этапе компиляции.
____

@guci: У вас по сути массив Long'ов, и при помощи трюка с Object в него можно засунуть не только Long (и не только long, который будет при этом автобоксирован и превратится в нужный Long), а вообще что угодно. В этом суть проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что автоматом преобразовываются в int целочисленные значения переменных.
Нужно явно это делать (преобразовывать), так будет все ок:

```
array[0] = (long)1;
```

И так будет тоже ок:

```
long[] array = new long[1];
array[0] = 1;
```

В вашем примере используете тип обертку лонга, этот тип ожидает исключительно лонг, а компилятор вам подсовывает инт. Вернее, компилятор подсовывает ему вот такое:

```
Integer.valueOf(1);
```

Comment: > так будет все ок: array[0] = (long)1

1L же.

Comment: но почему автоматически не преобразовывается? так же преобразовывается:
int a = 2;
long b = 3;

Comment: он автоматом преобразовывает в Integer, а у вас массив из Long, это классы обертки, а не примитивы, хоть у них и один предок Number, связь у них не такая, как у примитивов. Если у вас есть объект типа Integer, то никаких автоматических преобразований из одного типа объекта в другой не будет, есть специальные методы у данных классов для этого.

Вам нужно указать компилятору, что вы ему лонг(примитив) предлагаете, тогда он автоматом преобразует его в тип Long. Почитайте про автобоксинг и про классы обертки, тогда станет все ясно.

Comment: Вот явно видно, во что преобразовался ваш примитив:
Object[] array = new Number[1];

array[0] = 1;

System.out.println(array[0]);

System.out.println(array[0].getClass().getSimpleName());

Выведет:
Integer

Comment: Но почему не происходит ошибки компиляции? Здесь она произойдёт: Integer a = 1;
Long b = a;

Comment: В смысле почему IDE не подсвечивает? Он не на столько умный, тут "ошибка всплывает" во время преобразований. В Integer a = 1; Long b = a; уже все строго типизировано, поэтому IDE "видит" ошибку.
Вы же не удивляетесь, почему IDE не подсвечивает тут ошибку:
int[] arr = new int[1];
arr[5] = 1;